# How to call base constructor inside constructor depending on some parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, constructor

How to call base constructor inside constructor  depending on parametres?
For example:

```
public SomeConstructor (){
       if(SomeParameter == "something") //here call base("something");
          else //here call base("something else")
}
```

in my example

```
SomeParameter
```

could be for example local computer name.

To explain what am i doing, i want to determine constructor depending on computer name. I am working on MVC project, and i still forget change name of connection string when i'm publishing project on the server. so, i want to specify if computer name == my computer name, then call

```
:base("DefaultConnection")
```

otherwise, call for example

```
:base("ServerConnectionString")
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok, sorry. i won't do that next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that way, you can only call as in your latter examples, and even then, both your examples are passing a string and not changing the parameter type, so it seems senseless this way (they're not even different constructors you're calling). You could get away with calling the constructor in the conventional way, and making sure the provided value is the valid one prior to that.

As an off the cuff example, consider the following:

```
public SomeConstructor() 
  : base(Configuration.ConnectionString) {

}

public static Configuration {
  public static string ConnectionString {
    get { 
      /* some logic to determine the appropriate value */
#if DEBUG
      return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DebugConnectionString"]; 
#else
      return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReleaseConnectionString"]; 
#endif
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works very good. I don't know why i didn't hit on that idea before :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't call different constructors, but you can send different values into the same constructor, using the conditional opreator:

```
public SomeConstructor ()
  : base(SomeParameter == "something" ? "something" : "something else") {
}
```

If you need to use different base constructors, you would make one constructor for each, and use a static method to choose between different constructors. Example:

```
private SomeConstructor() : base("some", "thing") {}

private SomeConstructor(bool flag) : base("some", "other", "thing") {}

public SomeConstructor Create() {
  if (SomeParameter == "something") {
    return new SomeConstructor();
  } else {
    return new SomeConstructor(true);
  }
}
```

(Here I used a boolean parameter just to make the constructor signatures different. You may have different data to send into them, so that you don't need to differentiate them that way.)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public class TestInherit : Child
{
    public TestInherit()
        : base(Environment.MachineName=="MyPC" ? "here" : "there")
    {
    }

}

public class Child
{
    public Child(string name) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too. Your idea is also very usefull. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use one connection string with different values depending on build configuration. This is achieved by [Config file transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In *Web.config* use

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Foo" connectionString="DefaultConnection" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

If *Web.Release.config* use

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Foo" connectionString="ServerConnectionString"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When you will build your project in Release configuration, *Web.config* will have *Foo* connection string with value `ServerConnectionString`.

Also I recommend you to use [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) package which allows you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration.

---

As I mentioned in comments, if you don't want to depend on building configuration for some reason, then you can ask your dependency injection framework (Unity, Ninject, etc) for correct parameter. Here is sample for Ninject:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().WithConstructorArgument("bar", 
     context => IsLocalMachine ? "DefaultConnection" : "ServerConnectionString");
```

When Foo will be instantiated (DbContext in your case), appropriate string will be passed to constructor:

```
public class Foo : FooBase, IFoo
{
    public Foo(string bar) : base(bar)
    {            
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianKsiężarczyk btw if you want different strings depending on machine name instead of build configuration, then it's easily solved with dependency injection frameworks (appropriate connection string name will be injected into constructor)

Comment: @AdrianKsiężarczyk I've added DI sample for you :)